# Continuing a short story

Tags: fiction, short-story, narrative

I got an assignment from my teacher that tells me to continue a story that he started. The limit is 1 page. The scenario is that Rose (the main character) is looking for a missing painting, inside someone's house. (They stopped at the point where she opened it) I don't really know how to write/continue the short story. Where should I begin? I don't have a lot of ideas and I brainstormed a little bit but I couldn't think of anything.

Comment: We can't really help with homework assignments, since the point of it is to test and see how _you_ think you should move forward. But the writing tutor part of me wants to help - you say you don't have "a lot of ideas", meaning you do have some. Try writing through one idea without thinking. Then go back, take a part you like, and write again around that. If this is only 1 page, you can write a lot of drafts pretty quickly. Ask questions, put your self in your characters shoes, and, mainly, **just write**. :)

Comment: What is the conflict so far in your teacher's short story?  If there isn't one, you have to create one.

Comment: Go ask your teacher for help.  And talk to your classmates.  You're asking us to do your homework for you.  Not remotely on topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot tell you what to write or help you brainstorming - that's your task as a writer. However, we can try to assist you with *how* to brainstorm.

It is very helpful, looking at a situation, to ask questions. How does your character feel in the situation? What is she thinking about? Why is she there? Going forward, what does she find? Etc.

The question I find most useful when I'm stuck is **what would make the most trouble for my character?** Stories strive on tension. You want tension, you need trouble. Keeping in mind who your character is, what her goal is, and what kind of story you want to tell (horror, humour, etc.), what would cause the most trouble?

Then, of course, you would need to resolve whatever trouble you've landed your character into. Or not resolve it - she might succumb to whatever. Either way, you'd need to wrap up whatever is happening.